# Can only deploy contracts on Parity when --geth flag is invoked

Tags: truffle, parity, contract-deployment, gas

When I try to *truffle migrate* a contract on a private blockchain using Parity, I get

> The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount

But when I do *everything* else the same, except adding "--geth --force-ui" to the Parity command line, it works fine.

This seems strange.  Has anyone had this problem?  Is there a known solution?